# iOS launch image and status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display, iphone-5

In an iOS app, historically, the launch image was supposed to have a 20/40px unused area on top where the status bar would appear during app launch. In my app, I would just have a while stripe there.

Now I'm adapting my app for 4" screens, I've provided a Default-568h@2x.png image with an identical stripe. It does not work the way it used to (at least on the simulator) - the stripe appears **below** the status bar, and the rest of the image is shifted down.

Am I supposed to crop the image now? The screen size, however, is 640x1136, exactly like the suggested launch image size. If I crop the status bar from the top, what will go in the bottom?

Comment: Have you tried cropping it from the top to see what appears at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem, looks like it may be a bug when Xcode chooses the right image for 568h. Try removing the images and adding them back to the project with copying them to the folder and then adding them to project.

Comment: Is that a simulator-only issue by any chance? I don't have any 5G devices, can't test.

Comment: No, i don't think its a simulator issue. It happened on my device when i was testing with it. But that was, if it happened on the simulator, it happened on the device.

Comment: Simply re-adding to the project does not help. Do I need to list the new splash screen it in the Info.plist, or elsewhere? Or change the file type? The way it looks, it's as if my old splash screen is used instead, vertically stretched. But the system notices the new one, since my views do appear properly resized.

Comment: And **now** it went away. Most weird. I did not do anything, just a few rebuilds and a NIB fix.